# Emit data from react to node server using socket.io-client

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I tried to emit data from client to server using [socket.io-client][1] and the following code i added in react app.

```
import io from "socket.io-client";

var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3002');
socket.emit("room", 'room1');
```

and in server side followimg code added

```
const app = express();
const http = require("http").Server(app);

const io = require("socket.io");
var socket = io(http);
socket.on("connection", socket => {
  console.log("user connected");
  socket.on('room', function(room){
      console.log("room", room);
      socket.join(room);
  });
});

app.listen(3002);
```

But, i didn't receive any data on server side even socket connection established and emit from server to client is working fine.
Thank you
[1]: https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-client

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the express server, but are never telling it to listen on a port.

You need to add app.listen() like this:

```
const app = express();
const http = require("http").Server(app);

app.listen(3002);

const io = require("socket.io");
var socket = io(http);
socket.on("connection", socket => {
  console.log("user connected");
  socket.on('room', function(room){
      console.log("room", room);
      socket.join(room);
  });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, can you see my question again. I forgot add my full code server is running finde but, i'm not receiving data from client to server